# sorting on a new field

Tags: ruby, sorting, mongodb, null, mongoid

So I did have a array of events which I ordered by calling sort on it

```
all.sort {|a,b| b.time<=> a.time}
```

Now recently I have added a new field to my object to include a "uploaded_at" time. I would like to firstly sort by "Time" and then by "Uploaded_at" time (as the 'Time' field is simple a date without any time on it.

I need to bare in mind that all old "Events" will not have a value for "Uploaded_at" and so this method could not exist. How can I go about that? (I do not care about the order of two events that have the same Time and no uploaded_at values

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
all.sort_by { |x| [x.time, (x.uploaded_at rescue Time.utc(1970))] }
```

Comment: it produces a NoMethodError when I do that!

Comment: I don't think you can compare arrays with `nil`s in it, a default base time should be set, for example: `[x.time, x.respond_to?(:uploaded_at) ? x.uploaded_at : Time.utc(1970)]`

Comment: ok @tokland, I edited my answer again.  I think the OP should be able to figure things out from here.

Comment: @David: yeah, pointing to sort_by is all the OP should need. As a side note: personally I dislike very much in-line rescues... I understand you use it just to be succint, but an explicit check is usually preferrable in real code.

Comment: @tokland Yeah you're probably right.  I'm just not sure if `respond_to` plays nicely with things like `method_missing` which might be used in this mongoid thing he's using that I'm not familiar with, so I went with the safer route which is to rescue it.  The OP should try your way and mine and see which one he likes better.  It's pretty weird to me that different rows in the same table would have different methods defined.

Comment: i seem to be very close but the second order doesn't seem to be working for some reason.. for example I have it ordered so There is a Event Without Uploaded_at - Event With Uploaded_at - Event Without - Event With - Event With.... it seems to be doing the same as not having the x.uploaded_at section of the code.... I can order by just uploaed_at but this doesnt produce the a effect for all older events

Comment: Well @Steve you need to learn more trouble shooting skills.  `sort_by` returns the result a NEW array so are you using the new array?  Maybe your data is bad or uploaded_at returns nil sometimes.  How about you take the new array and inspect `new_array.collect { |x| [x.time, (x.uploaded_at rescue Time.utc(1970))] }` to make sure you are sorting by the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to handle the `nil` values in `uploaded_at` with some care. The problem is that `x <=> nil` and `nil <=> x` will be `nil` except when `x.nil?` and sorting requires the `<=>` operator to return a Fixnum.

One option is to map `nil`s to some non-`nil` value that will always sort properly, `Time.new(0)` perhaps:

```
all.sort_by { |a| [a.time, a.uploaded_at || Time.new(0)] }
```

`Array#<=>` operators component-by-component and the above removes the `nil` problem. If you want `nil`s at the other end then choose something large instead of `Time.new(0)`.

Another options is to handle the `nil`s manually:

```
all.sort do |a, b|
    x = a.time <=> b.time
    if(x != 0)
        x
    elsif(a.uploaded_at.nil? && b.uploaded_at.nil?)
        0
    elsif(a.uploaded_at.nil?)
        1
    elsif(b.uploaded_at.nil?)
        -1
    else
        a.uploaded_at <=> b.uploaded_at
    end
end
```

You would, of course, adjust the `elsif(a.uploaded_at.nil?)` and `elsif(b.uploaded_at.nil?)` branches to put the `nil`s where you want them.